# Any way to prevent gnuplot xticlabel from truncating long strings?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with several lines set up like this:

```
"Simplifying or consolidating services or product portfolios"   .35
```

When I try to plot this in gnuplot as follows, any string longer than 51 characters is truncated to 52 characters with the last character being a symbol of some sort (e.g. a box, thorn, y umlaut).

```
plot 'force.dat' u 2 title ' ', '' u 0:(0):xticlabel(1) w l
```

I haven't been able to find any information about a maximum legnth for xticlabel, but it seems like I've hit the maximum.  Is there anything I can do to print out the full string on the graph?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a dynamic way of increasing the length. It is hard-coded.

What you can do is compile your own version where the constant `MAX_ID_LEN` is set to some reasonably large number (it's defined in file `gp_types.h`).

(I reported this as a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102055&aid=3585182&group_id=2055).)