# Gnuplot xticlabels with several lines

Tags: plot, gnuplot

if I add a xticlabel that uses 3 lines gnuplot cuts at the middle of the second line.
Is there any method to have xticlabels with several lines?

This is my data file:

```
"[17h30,19h00] 25" 1
"[03h30,10h00] 21" 1
"[03h00,12h00] 26" 2
"[18h00,19h30] 27" 3
"[20h30,22h00] 25" 4
"[13h00,14h30] 25" 4
"[19h30,21h30] 25" 5
"[14h30,16h00] 25" 5
"[16h30,18h00] 25" 5
"[09h30,15h00] 25" 9
```

And this is my gnuplot code:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set output '| epstopdf --filter --outfile=hist.pdf'
set auto x
set yrange [0:10]
set style histogram clustered
set boxwidth 0.95 relative
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
plot 'hist.dat' using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes lc rgb'blue90' notitle
```

Finally this is the graph produced:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Potential Problem 1: xtics overlap

You have a few options to help fix the xtic problem.

### 1) Rotate the xtics

```
set xtics rotate by -45
```

This will set the xtics to print at an angle from top-left to bottom-right.

### 2) Change the font size

```
set xtics font ",4"
```

You could make the font size tiny but unreadable.

### 3) add a gap between the bars of the graph

```
set style histogram gap 4
```

### 4) Change the data file

If you have control over the data file, you could try inserting some newlines into the xtic labels, e.g.

```
"17h30\n19h00\n25" 1
```

### Potential Problem 2: xtics too long in general

I'm not quite sure from your question, but you may be running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538627/any-way-to-prevent-gnuplot-xticlabel-from-truncating-long-strings).  Gnuplot has a built-in limit for the number of characters in a label, which is set to 50 in older versions of gnuplot and is 200 more recently.  The post I linked to includes a workaround, which is to compile a version of gnuplot with an increased `MAX_ID_LEN` constant.

Comment: I don't think that is the main reason. Each one of my xticlabels are less than 50 characters. In fact each one takes 17 characters.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't see from your data file and plot how the xtics are taking three lines.  I am trying to understand what your issue is.  The xtics do seem to be cut off, is that the main problem?  If so it might be best to modify the data file before plotting.

Comment: OK, see my edits.  Side question: you have an unusual output set for the eps terminal--do you not have the `pdf` or `pdfcairo` terminals available?  In that case you would not have to use an external program to convert from eps to pdf.  To see your available terminals, run `print GPVAL_TERMINALS` at the gnuplot command line.

Comment: In your case, you would issue `set terminal pdf` or `set terminal pdfcairo`, then `set output 'myoutput.pdf'`, instead of setting the eps terminal like you do currently.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but in my case the labels where taken from two columns (a stringcolumn(1) and a numeric column(2)), while y-data in 3-rd column.

I split the labels in two using newline "\n"

```
using 2:3:xticlabels(stringcolumn(1) . "\n\n" . stringcolumn(2))
```

Basically inside xticlabels() you can give any string expression, for example
i also needed some numeric formatting for which i used instead of stringcolumn(2) the following expression:

```
gprintf('%1.0t*10^{%S}',column(2))
```

hope it helps